# How to avoid rendering the Logged Out page when using IdentityServer3

Tags: identityserver3

When logging out from the application, IdentityServer's "You are now logged out of the application" view gets displayed. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect option to true in AuthenticationOptions (it's set to false by default). Then, the user would be redirected back to the post_logout_redirect_uri.

More details here:
https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/authenticationOptions.html